# Where expression with negative values returns incorrect results

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-core-2.0

When using SQLite as a database for EFCore, the following expression doesn't work:

```
Where(x => x.Price > -1)
```

This expression will return items where Price is -5. One workaround is to use Decimal.Negate and reverse the expression, but that shouldn't be needed. Both methods work fine with using SQL as the database. Am I missing something, or is this really a bug with SQLite?

Repro below:

Given Db Model **Item**:

```
class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and db context

```
class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and the following repo:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");

    connection.Open();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
                        .UseSqlite(connection)
                        .Options;

    var context = new TestDbContext(options);

    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item{Id = 1, Name = "Item 1", Price = 100},
        new Item{Id = 2, Name = "Item 2", Price = 10},
        new Item{Id = 3, Name = "Item 3", Price = 0},
        new Item{Id = 4, Name = "Item 4", Price = -1},
        new Item{Id = 5, Name = "Item 5", Price = -5}
    };

    context.Items.AddRange(items);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var query1 = context.Items.Where(x => x.Price > 0).Select(x => x.Name);
    var results1 = await query1.ToArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Items with price greater than 0 - {string.Join(',', results1)}");

    var query2 = context.Items.Where(x => x.Price > -1m).Select(x => x.Name);
    var results2 = await query2.ToArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Items with price greater than -1 - {string.Join(',', results2)}");

    var query3 = context.Items.Where(x => decimal.Negate(x.Price) < 1).Select(x => x.Name);
    var results3 = await query3.ToArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Items with price greater than -1 - {string.Join(',', results3)}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result of query2 produces Item 1, 2, 3 and 5, where only Item 1, 2, 3 are expected.

Comment: It doesn't return `item 4` but it does return `item 5`? What a weird bug

Comment: Works here https://dotnetfiddle.net/j7epeN Perhaps make sure to specify decimal? i.e. `-1m` instead of `-1`

Comment: @TyCobb you are just using Linq to Objects in your example, not EFCore and SQLite. And no, adding **m** doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Correct. No way to for anyone except a few to possibly test your situation. Just needed to verify that it's not something unrelated and your first line of example code shows you aren't using decimal.

Comment: Curious though what happens if you remove the Async calls.

Comment: Is it possible its converting to a string internally.  Where -5 would be greater than -1?

Comment: @TyCobb removing all Async calls doesn't make a difference. And anyone can run this very easily. It's just a nuget package and the sample runs Sqlite  as an in memory data store, so there is no backend to set up.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Looks like you were correct. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10249